# Symfony form with EntityType field yields a 'This value should not be blank' error if the field has a Valid() contraint in the object class

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a `Phone` class and a `Country` class in a Symfony 2.8 project.
One of the fields of the `Phone` class is `$country` which is a `Country` object.

I also have a form with an EntityType field, which I use to select from a list of the countries in my database.

My problem is that when I select a country from the dropdown menu generated by the EntityType field and submit the form, I get the error 'This value should not be blank.' several times above the EntityField dropdown menu.

What is weird is that I do a `dump($phone)` after `$form->handleRequest($request);` and the $country field shows the correct Country object fetched from the database.

This only happens when the `@Assert\Valid()` constraint is on the `$country` field. Once i remove it the error goes away.
The thing is that I want to continue to validate the country field of my `Phone` class.

Any ideas on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

`Phone` class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Phone
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="phones", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="natural_pk", columns={"phone_name", "country_id", "phone_number", "extension"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PhoneRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Phone
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="int")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Country
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $country;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone_number", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(max=20)
     */
    protected $phoneNumber;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set phoneNumber
     *
     * @param string $phoneNumber
     *
     * @return Phone
     */
    public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phoneNumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Country $country
     *
     * @return Phone
     */
    public function setCountry(\AppBundle\Entity\Country $country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Country
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }
}
```

Country class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Country
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="countries")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CountryRepository")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="int")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    protected $countryName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone_code", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(max=10)
     */
    protected $phoneCode;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->phoneCode;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set countryName
     *
     * @param string $countryName
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setCountryName($countryName)
    {
        $this->countryName = $countryName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get countryName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountryName()
    {
        return $this->countryName;
    }

    /**
     * Set phoneCode
     *
     * @param string $phoneCode
     *
     * @return Country
     */
    public function setPhoneCode($phoneCode)
    {
        $this->phoneCode = $phoneCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phoneCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhoneCode()
    {
        return $this->phoneCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the countries actually valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem.
It turns out that my `Country` class actually has another field from a bidirectional association called `$provinces` and this field has a `Valid()` constraint as well:

```
/**
 * @var Province[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Province", mappedBy="country")
 *
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $provinces;
```

This was causing the error, I guess because if `$provinces` is an empty array, the `Country` object doesn't fulfill Symfony's `Valid()` constraint.

In order to solve it I had to either remove the `Valid()` constraint on the `$provinces` field in the Country class, or on the `$country` field in the `Phone` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable validation by specifying non-existed validation group in you form type:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(['validation_groups' => ['no-validation']]); // Do not validate entities.
}
```

Didn't find a better solution :/